# Propel 1.7 double pluralization of the method names used for accessing related objects

Tags: mysql, propel

I am using (for the first time) propel 1.7 and the propel-gen shell script provided with the installation. The schema.xml is generated from an existing database with `propel-gen reverse`, after that the classes are generated with `propel-gen om`.

My database structure is built in a such manner that it provides translations for various data in a separate table, with a one to many relationship.
This is an example:

```
TABLE 'buildings'
  'id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'address' varchar(255) NOT NULL,

TABLE 'building_description_translations'
  'building_id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  'lang' varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  'description' varchar(1023) NOT NULL,
```

`building_description_translations.building_id` has a foreign key to `buildings.id`. Also, `building_description_translations`'s primary key is over the `building_id` and `lang` columns.

So far so great, the propel generator works like a charm, except that the method names used to access the related objects from relationships end up being pluralized twice:

```
// file build/classes/myproject/om/BaseBuildings
class BaseBuildings{
    //...

    // note the TranslationSS
    public function getBuildingDescriptionTranslationss($criteria = null, PropelPDO $con = null)
    {
    //...
    }   

}
```

Also, my build.properties file looks like (besides the database configuration):

```
propel.builder.pluralizer.class = builder.util.StandardEnglishPluralizer
propel.samePhpName = true
propel.addVendorInfo = true
```

Is there a way to control this double-pluralization, without interfering with the existing database schema? I've already searched for an answer, but I couldn't find anything relevant to this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - the easiest way is to create a custom Pluralizer class which will suit my needs, based on the original one which is located at 
`generator\lib\builder\util\StandardEnglishPluralizer.php`

Let's say the new Pluralizer is

`generator\lib\builder\util\MyEnglishPluralizer.php`

In `build.properties`, the pluralizer configuration needs to be chaged accordingly.

`propel.builder.pluralizer.class = builder.util.MyEnglishPluralizer`

And then, regenerate the classes using `propel-gen om`

In my case, I only had to add an entry to the `$_plural` property

```
protected $_plural = array(
        // ...
        'ons' => 'ons'
    );
```

**Note:** I've used the `propel-gen` script provided with the propel installation, and not the one from the PEAR package.